# ASP.NET / Oracle issue: TNS Could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, oracle

I've got a local copy of an ASP.NET web application running in Visual Studio 2010. The code is an exact duplicate of the code running on my dev environment.

When I try to connect to my Oracle database through ASP.NET, it throws a "TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified." The weird thing is this database is in my TNSNAMES.ORA file, and when I use TNSPING or Microsoft Data Link to connect, it works fine.

I tried tinkering with the permissions on my Oracle directory, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: betting on a x86/x64 issue. What are the architecture of your prod and dev environment?

Comment: Production/dev server is Windows 2003. My local machine (where I'm having the problem) is Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: Another possibility - if you have more than one Oracle client installed, check your PATH and make sure you are looking at the right tnsnames.ora file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the Oracle Database client (x86 or x64).

Make sure you have the PATH configured to use the Oracle bin folder:

> PATH=C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin

Make sure your **tnsnames.ora** file is in the directory:

> C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin

You can try and use the following connection string:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.1)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYDATABASE)));User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword;
```

UPDATE:

I don't have this environment variable (cause I use the extended connection string) but someone [here](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/oracle-connection) and [here](http://yyosifov.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/ora-12154-tnscould-not-resolve-connect.html) suggest to add **TNS_ADMIN**.

Comment: OK, this is weird...when I take the connection information from my TNSNames.Ora file and plug it into my connection string, it works fine. I've verified which TNSNames.ora file using TNSPING.

Comment: @Tim: I have updated my answer. As I said I prefer not to worry about the TNSNames.Ora and use the extended connection string.

Comment: The extended connection string worked for me. Oracle and I just don't get along very well. I'll have to remember this for my next project so I don't lose an hour or two of troubleshooting again.

Answer (score 5):

Using TNS:

(For ASP.NET Core you need the TNS_ADMIN environment variable pointing to the directory where tnsnames.ora is located)

```
Data Source = TORCL; User Id = myUsername; Password = myPassword;
```

Not using TNS:

```
Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = MyHost) (PORT = MyPort))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = MyOracleSID));
User Id = myUsername; Password = myPassword;
```

Answer (score 2):

If all the above validations fail, try the following.
This is what solved my issue.
It is the name of the TNS entry in tnsnames.ora file.

Example:
I had abc.xyz = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));

I still got ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Then I changed it to, 
abcxyz = ()
and it worked.

Basically I removed special characters like . and _ in the TNS entry name.

Answer (score 1):

1. Installed VirtualBox 5.0.20
2. Installed CentOS 7 on VirtualBox
3. Installed Oracle 11g R2 (11.0.2)
4. Create a database
5. Installed Windows 10 on VirtualBox
6. Installed VisualStudio Professional 2012 and step by step update SP1 to SP5
7. Update Nuget Package Manager
8. Run in Nuget Package Manager Console: Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
9. Create a web project.
10. Keep a tnsnames.ora file in the project bin folder

    ### TNSNAMES.ORA

MYDB= (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.2)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SID_NAME)));

use the source code in step 12 except the connection string as below:

```
string constr = "user id=test;password=test;data source=MYDB";
```

or follow steps 12.

11. Used the following namespace in code
    using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
    using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;
12. To connect Oracle Database used the following statement:

    string constr = "user id=test;password=test;data source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.2)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SID_NAME)))";

    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
    try
    {
    con.Open();
    ViewData["Message"] = "Connected";
    con.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    ViewData["Message"] = ex.Message;
    }
13. That's it. It's worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

When I try to connect Oracle Data source from Visual Studio.

Steps to resolve this issue.

Make sure you have Oracle client installed on your system, also Oracle Wallet Manager installed.

1. Open Oracle Wallet Manager and Add certificates provided by your organization.
2. Navigate to ‘C:\APP\ORACLE\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin’ (or similar folder structure in your desktop) folder and replace the ‘tnsnames.ora’ and ‘sqlnet.ora’ files with attached.
3. In the C:\ORACLE\product\11.2.0.3\network\admin --> Add SQL.net.ora and tnsnames.ora files
4. In SQL.net.ora file, modify the wallet path as created in the step-1

Restart your system and start creating Shared Data Source.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible scenario where this error occurs is if you are using IISExpress locally to test.

When the TNS entry is added/modified, IISExpress must be restarted so that the new value is honored.

In my case, I was debugging an application and had stopped it to modify the TNS entry, however I then ran the application again but the same IISExpress instance was used to run the API.

Once I stopped the app and manually closed IISExpress, I was able to make my modifications on TNSNAMES work properly on the next execution.